# How to pass parameters while invoking script in cron?

Tags: bash, cron

I want to execute a script with some parameters as a cron job. I have configured the crontab using `crontab -e` with the following content

```
*/2 * * * * /root/todo-api/workspace/docker.sh c4e842c79337
```

but it is not working. When I used

```
*/2 * * * * /root/todo-api/workspace/docker.sh
```

it worked. How to pass parameters while invoking a script in cron? Here is my docker.sh script and it works if I directly execute it from shell.

```
CONTAINER=$1    

RUNNING=$(docker inspect --format="{{.State.Running}}" $CONTAINER 2> /dev/null)

if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "UNKNOWN - $CONTAINER does not exist."
  exit 3
fi

if [ "$RUNNING" == "false" ]; then
  echo "CRITICAL - $CONTAINER is not running."
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"routing_key": "3ef61cda125048a390d46cdb8d425590","event_action": "trigger","payload": {"summary": "Docker Container '$CONTAINER' down", "source": "'$CONTAINER'", "severity": "critical" }}' "https://events.pagerduty.com/v2/enqueue"
  exit 2
fi

echo "OK"
```

Comment: How did you create this job?

Comment: Why do you have a leading `"` in the 2nd case?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: "but it is not working"  -  please elaborate this statement.

Comment: Given the limited problem description here, it's much easier to assume that there is a problem inside of your `.../docker.sh` script. Please update your Q with the minimum amount of code that other can reproduce your problem with. Currently, it is a mystery ;-) . Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first crontab entry looks correct. Since there is no `#! /bin/bash` line, you might need to put bash in front of the invocation, e.g.

```
*/2 * * * * /bin/bash /root/todo-api/workspace/docker.sh c4e842c79337
```

---

According to [docker inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/)

> **Usage**
>
> ```
> docker inspect [OPTIONS] NAME|ID [NAME|ID...]
> ```

the second invocation without `$CONTAINER` must fail, because `inspect` expects a name or some id.

To debug this further, follow this question [How to debug a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/1741542) and keep the output from stderr, e.g. remove `2>/dev/null`.

Answer (score 4):

You pass the parameters just as you would do in the Shell.

A good way of testing it is by creating a simple `/home/script.sh` like:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "My first input is $1"
echo "And my second input is $2"
```

And so on ...

Then run it like so it executes every minute:

```
* * * * * /home/script.sh arg1 arg2 >> /home/cron_output.log
```

Use this procedure to make sure your own script is running as desired.
In my experience, everything before the `>>` is assumed as parameter for to the script.

Keep in mind that cronjob runs on its own detached shell, so you need to redirect STDOUT to a file to actually see it working.

Comment: Shouldn't the example be * * * * * /home/script.sh arg1 arg2 >> /home/cron_output.log

Comment: You're right. Thanks

Comment: No problem … glad I could help.